# c++ - non-trivial designated initializers not supported

Tags: c++, c

I am rebuilding a library with and found this error in this section of the code:

```
enum fix_version {
    FIX_4_0,
    FIX_4_1,
    FIX_4_2,
    FIX_4_3,
    FIX_4_4,
    FIX_5_0,
    FIXT_1_1,
};

static const char *begin_strings[] = {
        [FIXT_1_1]  = "FIXT.1.1",
        [FIX_4_4]   = "FIX.4.4",
        [FIX_4_3]   = "FIX.4.3",
        [FIX_4_2]   = "FIX.4.2",
        [FIX_4_1]   = "FIX.4.1",
        [FIX_4_0]   = "FIX.4.0",
};
```

The error I receive is: `sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported`. I have seen other examples of this error, but those are initializers from another `struct` and this one is from a simple `char`, so how can I solve this? The code comes from `.c` files and I am compiling it in `c++` through `cmake`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to put it into `extern C` or change `=` for dots `.` ?

Comment: Where are these "simple `char`" initializers you speak of?  I don't see any.

Comment: You cannot compile C as C++ in general. Compile the C library as C and then use it from your C++ code with a proper header and linking.

Comment: @FilipKočica `extern C` doesn't magically change the language.

Comment: Iam not dumb, ive just found out answer with this advice marked as answered. @FelixPalmen .

Comment: @FilipKočica so? Still a C++ compiler will not suddently accept C syntax if you use `extern C`. What's your point? I didn't say you were dumb or something like this...

Comment: @JoeAlmore It's probably impossible to **count** all the places on SO where you're told C++ and C are different languages and compiling C with a C++ compiler is a very bad idea. This might be the reason for downvotes, as you're attempting to do exactly that.

Comment: This is going to be in C++20 and some support already exists in at least C++17 with g++. However, strings do cause problems.

Comment: The code compiles using gcc 10.3 (clang 13 gives a warning) **if you sort the designated initializers** to match the enum order. Also, you have to add an initializer for the "FIX_5_0" enum. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/c7qxTKKzf). The advantage over the only answer given below is that as soon as you add another entry to `enum fix_version` the code will not compile. This will remind you to add the respective string to `begin_strings`. Sorry, I cannot add an answer, that's a pity.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent C++ code would look like this:

```
enum fix_version {
    FIX_4_0,
    FIX_4_1,
    FIX_4_2,
    FIX_4_3,
    FIX_4_4,
    FIX_5_0,
    FIXT_1_1
};

static const char *begin_strings[] = {
        "FIX.4.0",
        "FIX.4.1",
        "FIX.4.2",
        "FIX.4.3",
        "FIX.4.4",
        0,
        "FIXT.1.1"
};
```

This of course has the risk to forget fixing the array when the `enum` changes. But C++ just doesn't support designated array initializers.

The better option, as already explained in a comment, is to leave the library *as is* and compile it with a C compiler. If it has headers using `extern "C"` as appropriate, you can use it directly from your C++ project. If not, place the `#include`s for the library in an `extern "C"` block.